# cannot run tgz file in windows 7 virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, openldap

I'm doing a project for school, and I wanted to create an active directory domain on Windows 7 through rktools and other files, but nothing worked, so i'm trying openLDAP. Now, I've downloaded the openLDAP.tgz file, and I have no idea what to do with it on Windows. How do I make it "run" ?

Thank you for a fast answer.

Answer (score 3):

The tgz is the source for Linux.

Look at [openLDAP for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openldapwindows/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can open/extract .tgz files using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Though, I agree with @parkydr.  If you're installing on Windows, use the Windows tools.

Comment: Well, I opened it with 7-zip, that's the first thing that came to mind, but I couldn't get it to work. Thank you for that file, i was looking for it everywhere and couldn't find it. Maybe it's just that I've been working my ass off for 10 hours now, I don't make any sense...

Comment: A .tgz will "un-zip" twice.  First time gets rid of the gzip leaving a .tar file.  Second time actually un-tar's the file.